# Autocomplete the input field(type="text")

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have totally 4 (input) fields in **form** namely product name, Product name, Selling price and Purchased price. when I enter the something in the  Product name field it should show the suggestions(out of  so many products from Database) like google shows and when I click any suggestions it should populate the corresponding DB values in  the all 4 fields.  Please provide the sample code if you have so that I can refer the same. I know need to user the ajax+jQuery+mySQL+php. I don't how to use this all.

help me on this requirement

Comment: you need auto-complete kind of thing ?

Comment: yup.. autocomplete kind of thing. But based what I select in the product name field other corresponding values should display (from DB ) in the remaining there field

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Jquery:

```
$(function(){
        var arr = [];
        var availableTags = [];

        $.ajax({
            'url'   : 'getdata.php',
            'method': 'get',
            success : function(response){
                arr = JSON.parse(response);

                availableTags = Object.keys(arr).map(function (key) { return arr[key]; });
            },
            async   : false
        });

        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
```

Html:

```
<input type="text" id="tags" placeholder="Enter name like Jackson">
```

Php:

```
<?php
    require('connect.php');

    $getDetails = "SELECT id, concat(first_name,' ',last_name) as name FROM test.datatables_demo";
    $details    = mysqli_query($con, $getDetails);

    $response = array();
    if(mysqli_num_rows($details) > 0)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($details))
        {
            $response[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```